# Who gets the kill?

Tags: killing-floor-2

When you headshot kill zeds they can continue to walk for a short time before dying. Obviously the last headshot killed the zed, though subsequent shots speed up the process.

So if someone headshots a zed and another player needlessly unloads a clip into the zed afterwards, getting the final shot, who gets the kill and who gets the assist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The player which makes the kill, will get the kill, the player that got the headshot will achieve an assist.  However, unlike KF1, both players will be rewarded with full XP so it isn't as much of a problem when somebody steals your kill.

Using headshot is effectively just removing that creatures special ability, unless you shoot it again or it bleeds out - it's still alive and open.  It's just seen as very unclassy to get a kill from a headless creature.

Comment: I've been seeing a lot of people finishing zeds like this and it made me wonder why. Experience isn't so much the issue as much as cash for better weapons in the next wave. If you get more money from the final kill then a bad team will steal each other's kills for more money, wasting limited ammo on a walking dead zed.
Thanks for the answer!

Comment: But do both players get full money?

Answer (score 0):

The scenario is much like many other games that have a "down but not out" system.

The best way of thinking about this is `who was the last player to cause damage prior to a death?` - this is the person rewarded with a kill.  When bleeding out, the player is still alive.  If another player causes damage during this time then they will be the one rewarded with the kill.

The assist goes to the person who previously damaged the enemy.  However, in some games this may have other restrictions (e.g. must have caused a certain amount of damage, and/or within a specific time period compared to the kill itself).

I'm not sure if multiple people can be rewarded with an assist on the same death.  For example, if you take an headshot to cause an opponent to bleed out but 2 others empty their clip in the enemy, you may not get a kill or an assist.  In other games you wouldn't get the assist for this scenario, so it is very likely to be the same in this game.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike other games, in KF2, kills/assists matter very little.

To answer your question, the one who last damaged the zed before it died (that means fell to the ground etc) will get the kill. A zed whose head has been removed is not dead until it actually falls.

That being said, don't let it bother you if you remove a scrake's head, but someone else unloads all their 9mm ammo into it anyway. Both of you will get the same money and xp, regardless of who shot first/last.

Also, I would recommend unloading 1 bullet into a zed before it dies, if you weren't shooting it before its head was removed. This allows for easy xp and money gain

Example: SWAT player unloads half a clip into a scrake, you were fighting other zeds, you see the scrake's head get destroyed, so now you shoot it once (any weapon) so that you also get money and xp. This does not affect anything other than the kill/assist count (refer to the first line of my answer)